# Why doesn't IE stop my paragraph overflowing?

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a `<p>` tag in it, I pretty much only use chrome, and anyway I noticed my fonts are real fuzzy and a bit of reading revealed that chrome is known for fuzzy fonts, so I opened up IE to see what the fonts looked like there, sure enough the fonts weren't fuzzy in IE but I discovered a new issue. My paragraph is all in one line instead of a normal paragraph like in chrome ?

Here's Chrome

[image]

Here's IE

[image]

It's the exact same code in both screenshots.

```css
div.description {
 width: 400px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: #373737;
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #888888;
 color: white;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 overflow: auto;
 flex-direction: column;
 margin-right: 15px; 
}

.description p {
 margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="description">
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas libero orci, 
viverra vel neque sed, elementum molestie sem. Sed in est id metus pharetra 
interdum. Donec cursus diam sit amet est elementum volutpat. Nam suscipit eget 
leo at porttitor. Curabitur auctor ullamcorper leo. Aenean sollicitudin justo 
in elementum suscipit. Suspendisse potenti. Vestibulum vitae commodo tellus, 
in imperdiet ante. In luctus nec leo sed vulputate. Proin bibendum ipsum urna, 
a ornare ex blandit a.
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: IE doesn't support flexbox unprefixed (and I'm not sure if what it *does* support is consistent with the latest standard). Having said that, I'm not sure you really need flexbox for your layout.

Comment: flex box is causing the issue. You can use a fallback for IE browser by using IE specific css.

Comment: I don't need flexbox for this particular item, but I do for my layout, it is used extensively for what I've done so I can't really go change it. Why is it that IE is so ancient? I swear it doesn't support anything until 25years after its release

Comment: Are you using gulp-sass for your theme?  I recommend [autoprefixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autoprefixer) as an addon.